# Difference between ()=> and _=> and (_)=> in JS ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have notice that when I want to write a fat arrow function "**=>**" I can do `_=>`, `()=>`
or `(_)=>` and my code functions the same **(at least for my use cases)**

**Is there an actual difference between them?** If yes, **which one should I use?** I have been using `()=>` most of the time, but then one day I saw someone's code using `_=>` and I thought it looked cool, so I started using it too.

I saw this medium article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26 where the author states you can use `_=>` or `()=>` but doesn't specify if there's a difference.

Comment: An underscore is a valid identifier, and may be bound to a parameter if one exists.

Comment: @MaheerAli you are right. I updated my question.

Comment: `Is there an actual difference between them` - short answer is yes, the first specifies no function arguments, the others specify one

Comment: Worth noting that you can use `_=>` instead of `()=>` because JavaScript functions can be called with an arbitrary amount of arguments, no matter how many parameters the function has. That allows you to call a function with a single parameter (`_=>`) without passing arguments (e.g. `foo()`). Many (most?) languages do not allow this.

Comment: @FelixKling you are 100% right on that. I didn't even think that JS was taking _ as a parameter.

Comment: One scenario `_ => {}` could become a problem is if you use lodash / underscore in you project. The library won't be accessible in the arrow function body since the argument is shadowing it.

Comment: If you have one parameter you can use it without parentheses otherwise if you have 0 parameters or 2 and more parameters you need to use parentheses. Here you have one parameter only i.e '_' So parentheses are not mandatory.

Comment: @ATULSHARMA Why are you restating something that's been said multiple times in multiple answers?

Comment: `_` parameter is *generally* used when you don't need a certain parameter inside the function's body. For example, `Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i + 1)` generates an array of numbers from 1-10. Here, you only care about the index which is the second parameter

Comment: @pawel very good point!!

Comment: @adiga ohh that's a good one! i like that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The general form of a fat-arrow function is

```
(parameter-list) => function-body
```

If you don't have any parameters, you use a pair of empty parentheses:

```
() => {}
```

If you have a single parameter it's:

```
(x) => {}
```

Since `_` is a valid identifier in JavaScript, you can do:

```
(_) => {}
```

Now, a special rule applies: If you have only *one* parameter, you can skip the parentheses, so you get:

```
_ => {}
```

Please note that this is only valid if you have a single parameter, i.e. for two you always have to specify the parentheses:

```
(x, y) => {}
```

Now, on the right side, if your entire function only consists of a single statement with a `return`, such as

```
x => { return x; }
```

you can omit the curly braces and the `return`:

```
x => x
```

At least, this is true if on the right side you don't try to return an object, which would look like this (this code won't work!):

```
x => { value: x }
```

The reason why this does not work is that JavaScript can not distinguish this from a function body, which also uses curly braces, so now you have to wrap it in parentheses:

```
x => ({ value: x })
```

I think that's pretty much everything you need to know about the syntax of fat arrow functions.

Comment: Golo, Thanks for taking your time to answer my question. Now, when I use ` _=>` as a callback function  I'm using it without passing a parameter.

Comment: Then it doesn't make sense to do this (although it will still work). You should rather use `() => {}` to show that there are no parameters expected.

Comment: got it!! that means I'm using it wrong because I don't use the '_' and I'm not passing any parameter!! cool!!

Comment: Yes, because the _ in _=> itself would be a parameter.

Answer (score 6):

You should not use something just because it looks cool.

`_`  is often used to tell a linter (or reader) that you do not use an certain argument on purpose.

So if you have a callback with two arguments and you only use the second one you would write `(_, arg) => console.log(arg)` because if you would write `(foo, arg) => console.log(arg)` then the linter would complain about `foo` not being used.

And some APIs might have different behavior depending on the number of arguments the callback has (the middlewares of expressjs are an example for that), so if the API checks the `length` property of the callback then you might need to use a placeholder like `_`.

```js
var cb1 = _ => {};
var cb2 = () => {};

console.log(cb1.length)
console.log(cb2.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions take any number of parameters, just like "regular" functions. When there are no parameters, this is indicated by `() => {}`, similarly to `function() {}`. If you have *exactly one* parameter, though, the parenthesis may be omitted. This leads to a syntax like `_ => {}` like you've noted — this is identical to `(_) => {}`, as an underscore is a valid identifier (just like `foo`).

The runtime difference in your specific situation seems to be none, as you're (presumably) not passing any parameters, in which case `_` is undefined. You can easily verify this:

```js
const foo = _ => console.log(_);
foo(5); // logs 5
foo(); // logs undefined
```

That's not to say you *should* do it, just that it doesn't make a difference for now. If you added a parameter later, it could wreak havoc.

Comment: ohhhh nice. Now, when I use ` _=>` as a callback function I'm using it without passing a parameter. that means I'm using it wrong right?

Comment: Not wrong per se, just taking advantage of the fact that variables are `undefined` by default. If you tried to use it (as in the snippet in my answer), you'll see the behavior.

Comment: Right … it isn't needed here.

Comment: @ATULSHARMA That's what I said? "_If you have exactly one parameter, though, the parenthesis may be omitted._"